# UmnountOnBlur in createMaterialTopTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

How to unmount my screen when i change my tab. I am using `createMaterialTopTabNavigator()` from `@react-navigation/material-top-tabs` package.

i have tried to add unmonuntOnBlur in options but it doesnt work.

```
            <Tab.Screen name="addIdentity" component={addIdentityStack} options={{ title: 'Add Identity', unmountOnBlur: true }} />
            <Tab.Screen name="addVehicle" component={addVehicle} options={{ title: 'Add Vehicle', unmountOnBlur: true }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

The option 'unMountOnBlur' is not supported in material top navigator
you can check the supported options here
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/#options

Only drawer navigator and bottom tab navigator has this option

Comment: Then how i can unmount that screen. Basically there is camera on one tab so what i want is that when i swipe camera must be stopped.

Comment: Maybe you can use the https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-bottom-tab-navigator/#tabpress or the navigation listener to find a suitable event